# How to Get 'a.m.' format in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm having trouble to find the format for making like :

> 6 a.m.

I'm wondering if someone know which  string i need to enter to **outputFormat**
for make it the format as describe.

```
moment(openTime, inputFormat).format(outputFormat)
```

**This format:**

**'a.m.'**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get am pm from the date time string using moment js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971954/how-to-get-am-pm-from-the-date-time-string-using-moment-js)

Comment: @Dani , No because the format there is 'AM' and i asked for 'a.m.'

Comment: Follow this link for your answare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043820/display-12-hour-and-24-hour-time

Comment: Try this - `moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A').replace(/PM|AM/ig, (match) => [...match].join('.'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment.js doesn't have the exact format output you want, but you can produce it using two `.replace`s afterwards.

```js
var m = moment();

var s = m.format('h a');
console.log(s);

s = s.replace('am', 'a.m.').replace('pm', 'p.m.');
console.log(s);

m = m.add(12, 'hours');

s = m.format('h a');
console.log(s);

s = s.replace('am', 'a.m.').replace('pm', 'p.m.');
console.log(s);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.28.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```